# Finite mean implies finite variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let X a random variable if $\mathbb{E}[X]<\infty $ then $Var[X]< \infty$

I have tried to prove it by occupying the convectivity of the function $x^2$ but I haven't come up with anything so I have thought of some counterexample.
any suggestion or help I will be very grateful.

Comment: It is not true.

Comment: Take $f(x)={1 \over \sqrt{x}}$ on $(0,1)$ with uniform probability, then $Ef$ is finite but the variance is infinite.

Comment: @AlexR. Cauchy distribution does not have finite mean.

Comment: Also, the function $x \mapsto x^2$ is convex not concave.

Comment: Another common counter example is the pareto distribution. In you case set $\alpha \in (1, 2]$ then the first moment is finite but the second moment is not

Comment: Stable distribution with index $\alpha <2$ has finite moments up to  (not including ) $\alpha$  but no higher moments.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, I thought $f$ was your density function.  I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False. A $t$ distribution with 2 degrees of freedom has mean $0$ and undefined variance.

However, convince yourself by Jensen's inequality that a bounded $k$th moment implies a bounded $j$th moment for $0\leq j\leq k$, i.e. $E[|X|^k]<\infty\implies E[|X|^j]<\infty$.

Comment: Also note the variance is not well defined if the mean is not well defined.